# Trouble creating a conda env with working numpy: `ImportError: cannot import name scalarmath`

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, conda

I want to create a conda env (say B) that has a working numpy module. I have a working miniconda install and another conda env (say A) that has working numpy but no matter what approach I try I am unable to get another env with a working numpy.

The error I get when import is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import scalarmath
ImportError: cannot import name scalarmath
```

I have tried 3 approaches so far:

1. `conda create -n B python=2.7.10` and then `conda install -n B numpy=1.9.3`
2. `conda create --name B --clone A`
3. `conda create -n B python=2.7.10 numpy=1.9.3`

I get the same error every time. My platform is Ubuntu 14.04. The output of `which python` is:

```
/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/bin/python
```

My Python path looks like this:

```
~$ python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

['',
 '/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/sahaamo/miniconda2/envs/B/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.5-py2‌​.7.egg']
```

Comment: Are you sure you have switched into the newly created env? Try `~$ source activate B`, assuming that `B` is the name of the env you have just created. Your bash prompt should change to `(B)~$`. You can see which envs are available using `~$ conda info --envs`.

Comment: yup switched. Infact since numpy works in other environments anyway, not switching won't give the error.

Comment: Could you humour me and try creating a new env containing only numpy without cloning, e.g. using `conda create -n test python=2.7.10 numpy=1.9.3`? Do you see any unusual output from `conda`?

Comment: Wow that works. (This is clearly approach 3 in my question) I see what's going on here. I never actually imported numpy after creating blank environment. I installed pandas 0.16.2 which for some reason also upgrades numpy to 1.10.1. That's weird because I chose the exact same versions I have in virtual env A where everything works. Hence conda create -n B python=2.7.10 numpy=1.9.3 pandas=0.16.2 gives me exactly what I need.

Comment: It's difficult for me to judge what might have gone wrong in your original installation, but that's the beauty of having separate python environments - if something breaks then it's relatively easy to delete the problem environment and start again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the asker already has his problem solved, but i had a similar problem and came across the question so i'll post it for others. My problem was a rather silly one in that i didn't first specify `python` first before calling the script, so i i did `script.py` instead of `python script.py` so was not invoking Miniconda python executable, which means it wasn't able to import anything from the conda env.