# Cannot import name random/multiarray in conda environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, tensorflow, conda

I'm trying to run tensorflow in a conda environment. I started off by creating a python 2.7 environment with `conda create --name py27 python=2.7` and then activated it. Within the environment, I ran `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow`, which has tensorflow and numpy in the package, so hypothetically there shouldn't be any issues running numpy.

When I open up the python console within the environment, however, I'm continually getting `ImportError: No module named multiarray` and `ImportError: cannot import name Random` (I can import random with no issues, but then I get the multiarray issue) no matter how many times I uninstall/reinstall numpy/matplotlib (at one point I even uninstalled/reinstalled python) and no matter what versions of these I try to use, I keep on getting the same issue. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959028/trouble-creating-a-conda-env-with-working-numpy-importerror-cannot-import-nam).

Shortly: that issue has something with the version of numpy which is upgraded by another package by whatever reason. Try to specify version: `conda create -n NAME numpy=1.9.3 other_package`.

If that doesn't work, check if you have files in your working directory which names matches the names of some packages. For example, I had a similar problem after renaming `numpy.py.txt` (which is a sort of handmade cheatsheet) into just `numpy.py` and trying to `import numpy` within Python shell when I was in that directory.