# Python – ImportError: cannot import name X

Tags: python, windows, numpy, anaconda, qutip

I’m trying to run a single python script – which has worked in the past – using a couple modules. Some Googling suggested circular dependencies however that is only relevant for two files importing modules that depend on one another.

It seems to boil down to `scalarmath` not being found but I don't know why. My code is just simple functions defs for calculations  and then calling those functions (all in one file).

The output of my IDE is:

```
C:\Users\sg15\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe "P:/Solid State QT/NSMM/simulations/InteractionsOfTLF.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:/Solid State QT/NSMM/simulations/InteractionsOfTLF.py", line 13, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\sg15\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 122, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like, mplDeprecation, dedent, get_label
  File "C:\Users\sg15\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 33, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\sg15\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 185, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\sg15\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\sg15\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\sg15\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\sg15\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import scalarmath
ImportError: cannot import name scalarmath

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33959028/trouble-creating-a-conda-env-with-working-numpy-importerror-cannot-import-nam

Comment: I have, no luck as of yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was a classic uninstall reinstall jobby. It seemed that the packages became incompatible with a recent Windows update or an update to the packages themselves. Steps to fix (in case you need them):

**1)** Run python in a separate program, and try to import a library *e.g.* `import numpy`. You should still see the output error message in the image that was shown in the question. This indicates that it is not a local problem to our code. Close that python program/console/whatever.

**2)** Open command prompt (cmd) and run conda (command: `conda`). Then run the commands `conda install numpy` and `conda install matplotlib`. Click yes [y] to any options that are presented. These commands depend on which libraries were causing you trouble, of course.

**3)** In your python IDE's console, import the libraries again *i.e.* `import numpy` and `import matplotlib`. Run your code and you it should build just fine (providing you have no other bugs)

**Note:** You may have to uninstall the offending libraries giving you trouble in your conda environment in the Anaconda Navigator. To do this, select your conda environment (mine was called `qutip`) and remove the troublesome packages. They were `matplotlib` and `numpy` in this case.